# Cyclicity of remainders

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$$n^2\equiv0,1,4\mod8$$
I have noticed this pattern by hand:
$$0:8=0+0$$
$$1:8=0+1$$
$$4:8=0+4$$
$$9:8=1+1$$
$$16:8=2+0$$
$$25:8=3+1$$
$$36:8=4+4$$
$$49:8=6+1$$
So there is probably  a cyclic pattern of $0,1,4,1$. But I don't see why this should go on for infinity.

I can't rely on observation, so to me, it is not apparent that this cycle will go on forever. For example, seeing patterns will not help here. These are primes

$31,331,3331,... $

up to this number:
$
333333331$.

Therefore observation is not enough. Why are the remainders cyclic?

Comment: Note that for any integer polynomial, $P(n)\equiv P(n+8)\mod 8$. So the periodicity of any such polynomial (e.g. $n^2$) must have period that is a divisor of $8$. You can prove this first claim with the factorization of a difference of powers

Comment: Just to say that noticing this kind of pattern and wondering whether it might continue is at the root of a lot of interesting mathematics - so keep on noticing, and keep on asking: but perhaps the answers to this question will help you to make more progress yourself on the next one ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have$$(n+4)^2-n^2=8n+16\equiv0\pmod8.$$So, you have only to check what happens when $n\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. After that, the remainders enter into a cycle of order $4$.

Comment: Hmm, what seems to elude my mind is that by proving $8n+16\equiv 0 \mod8$, we only show that after 4 numbers, we once again arrive at the same reminder. 

Wait, I think it just clicked. By this, we showed that for any n, the number with the same remainder is exactly 4 numbers away. Am I right?

Comment: What I meant is that the remainder of the division of, say, $15^2$ by $8$ is equal to the remainder of the division of $11^2$ by $8$, which is equal to the remainder of the division of $7^2$ by $8$, which is equal to the remainder of the division of $3^2$ by $8$, which happens to be $1$.

Answer (score -1):

It is true that $(n+8)^2 = n^2 + 16n + 8^2 \equiv n^2 \text{ mod } 8$. So computing just the first $8$ square numbers is in fact enough to get the whole pattern.